# AngularJS - Using ng-switch in ng-repeat to conditionally apply HTML

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have a paginated list of video thumbnails I want to display in a Bootstrap fluid grid. I'm using a nested ng-repeat to first iterate over each list, for pagination, and an inner ng-repeat to iterate over each video thumbnail in the subarray. The grid is 3x6 so when the inner ng-repeat's index is a multiple of 5 (assuming $index starts at 0), I want to close a fluid row and start a new one.

```
<div ng-repeat="thumbList in thumbLists">
    <div ng-repeat="thumb in thumbList" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <a href="{{ thumb.URL }}">
                <img src="{{ thumb.thumbnailURL }}" width="160" height="85" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- ng-switch? -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The lists are populated by a REST service, such that when a user clicks on a 'next' button, a new array list' is pushed onto the 'lists' and an animation will slide over each 3x6 grid. The structure looks like:

```
$scope.thumbLists = [
    [{URL: url, thumbnailURL: thumburl}, ...],  // init
    [{URL: url, thumbnailURL: thumburl}, ...],  // pushed when user clicks 'next'
    ... etc
];
```

Everything I have is working properly, I'm just not sure how to conditionally add in the HTML to close a row and start a new one once that row hits 6 since the thumbnails are given in a single array.

For example, where I have the commented ng-switch, could I do something like:

```
<div ng-switch="$index">
    <div ng-switch-when="$index % 6 == 5">
</div>
```

Using 1.0.8 stable release. Must support IE8.

Temporary solution - removing the left margin for each element that is the first in it's row:

```
<div ng-repeat="thumbList in thumbLists">
    <div class="row-fluid>
        <div ng-repeat="thumb in thumbList" class="span2" ng-class="{nomargin: $index % 6 == 0}">            
            <a href="{{ thumb.URL }}">
                <img src="{{ thumb.thumbnailURL }}" width="160" height="85" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would still like to find a solution that where I can conditionally insert/remove HTML, perhaps using a directive.

Answer (score 0):

Would ng-grid work for you?  Might save you having to deal with the details.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Comment: Does angular-ui play nice with IE8?

Comment: I believe so but I'm not positive.  They did fix this IE8 bug (https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/268) so that seems encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

This works with `ng-switch` -- but may need some more tweaking to avoid the extra hidden span markup...

```
      <div ng-repeat="thumb in thumbList">
          <span ng-switch="$index % 5">
            <div class="row" ng-switch-when="0">
              <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="{{thumbList[$index+0].url}}" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="{{thumbList[$index+1].url}}" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="{{thumbList[$index+2].url}}" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="{{thumbList[$index+1].url}}" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="{{thumbList[$index+2].url}}" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div>
          </span>
      </div>
```

http://bootply.com/86985

Comment: Yeah, for each iteration of thumb, there's extra, empty HTML that's being output. For a single list of 18, that's 15 extra DOM elements.